# exe made by pyinstaller and moved to a diferent folder does not run (stops suddenly without showing the GUI)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using Eclipse/PyDev to develop Python application, in this case I need to make an exe from an application done with Python 3.8.6 32bits. The exe done by pyinstaller in onefile mode works perfectly but if I move it in any different folder it does not work. To be precise it starts and then kill itself in less than half of second without showing the GUI (I see it kills itself from the processes list). To use pyinstaller I am using auto-to-py-exe and the o.s. o the PC is Win7 SP1, the application has to work from Win7 and behind.
Any help and/or suggestion will be very appreciated,
Massimo

Comment: Do you have any absolute paths to other any directories or files?

Comment: Try to run your executable file in command prompt. It won't disappear even if it fails and then you can read the error it throws.

Comment: Ok, running the exe in console mode shows a couple of problems. The problem that stops the execution is a privileged access problem so the exe runs in any folder but not in the Programs folder. This because it has to access the app.log file writing to it. So the question is: how can I authorize my app to access the log file in privileged mode? I installed it using admin privilege (yes, i made the exe using pyinstaller and then I want to distribute an installer made by InnoSetup). The second point is that the app says it does not find the trnslations for base but it translates OK.

Comment: About the missing translations: I have them in my ./app/src/locales and they work in debug and also running from ./app/bat/dist and I packaged the locales folder with pyinstaller. This error is shown also if I move the app and the installed files in a  folder without privileged access and the app runs so I do not think it is a blocking problem, anyway if I copy the locales folder in the folder where the app is installed it disappears, so I think I have something to change in the i18n management, probably somewhere it access a relativa path that puinstaller manages to move in the temp folder